# VS Code Emmet shortcut key(tab or any other key) does not work but clicking from the menu works

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx, emmet

In VS Code, I tried using tab for expanding emmet abbreviations and it didn't work. i also changed the shortcut key to other combinations but no luck.

I have this in my emmet settings.json:

`"emmet.includeLanguages": { "javascript": "javascriptreact", }`

I have the following in keybindings.json:

```
{ "key": "tab",
"command": "tab",
"when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && !editorTabMovesFocus" }
```

The shortcut key does not work but going through the menu option works. `Edit -> Expand Emmet Abbreviation.`

Am i missing something? I am new to using emmet in vs code.

Comment: You can tab to expand on actual snippets. You need to keyboard down/up to the symbols that like a wrench or a lower case "n" with three dots underneath it then press tab.

Comment: I don't see the suggestions as well. Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It actually works now. Silly mistake. I had to wrap the following config in curly braces`{}`.
`{"emmet.includeLanguages": { "javascript": "javascriptreact", }}` instead of just `"emmet.includeLanguages": { "javascript": "javascriptreact", }`